# Is it possible to achieve something similar to word2vec using a graphdb?

Tags: nlp, graph-theory, graph-databases, gremlin, word2vec

Otherwise said replace eigen vectors with pattern matching and graph traversal and emulate dimension reduction?

I mean that given a semantic graph of english words compute something similar to:

`king - man = queen`

Which means that I can subtract from a graph a subgraph and score the resulting subgraph given a metric.

I don't expect that this will be a single neo4j or gremlin query. I'm interested in the underlying mechanic involved in reasoning at the same time globaly and localy over a graph database.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's important to remember the difference between graph databases as a storage solution and then using machine learning to extract connected graphs as vectors that represent features that are used to train a ML model proper.

The difference is that you can structure your data in such a way that makes it easier to find patterns that are suitable for creating a machine learning model. It's certainly a good idea to use Neo4j to do this but it's not something that comes out of the box. I've created a plugin to Neo4j that will extract hierarchical pattern matches from text using a genetic algorithm that I thought up. You can take a look here: http://www.kennybastani.com/2014/08/using-graph-database-for-deep-learning-text-classification.html

You can then use the resulting data to construct a word2vec model.

Comment: thanks for you quick and insightful answer. Indeed this looks like what I'm looking for. IIUC you don't move words outside of the graph representation using a matrix instead and only rely on hierarchical representation built via a genetic algorithm. What do you mean that it's a genetic algorithm? What is the population over which genetic selection and crossing is done the words of the labeled text?

Comment: who do you jump from the infered vector to `king - man = queen`?

Comment: If you think of this vector in 3D vector space model, which is a low dimensional feature space, you can train the model to understand antonyms. The expression `king - man` would take two vectors, subtract those models and locate the closest features in the vector space model. Iterate your training algorithm to increase accuracy.